# is it possible to have multiple classes inside php extension?

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

I would like to wrapp a .cc code that contains multiple public classes. Is it possible to do that ? how? Do I need to use multiple .cc files one for each class that i want to wrapp?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call a C++ class from php? This is incredibly difficult. Usually you have to write a php module (a lot of work). Alternatively you could take a look at [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) which would let you call your C++ code as a network service (sounds hard, but trust me it's easier than writing a php module).

Comment: i have the modules. but i have a handler only to the first class. i don't know how to create a handler to the second class

Answer (score 0):

<sup>I wonder what you are attempting to do... if motives were mentioned may be we can help better. Anyways....</sup>

To execute a compiled application you can use `execute()`;

```
$output = exec('/path/to/your/app');
```

Besides that, you can always write your own php extension....

Check out these tutorials

- http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021
- http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486-Wrapping-C-Classes-in-a-PHP-Extension
- http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=89796
- http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Developing-Custom-PHP-Extensions-Part-1/

AFAIK, Many developers use PHP to execute C functions, because it boosts performance quite remarkably.

Comment: i did use a php extension. i did create my own php .cc and config.m4. i succedded to create a handler over a single class (look at wrapping c++ classes) but i don't know how to create handler for the second class. need some help